# How to mock/stub react-native-firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, testing, jestjs, react-native-firebase

Does anyone know why this won't work?

My api call:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export default function getAuth() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      resolve(user);
    });
  });
}
```

My unit test that fails on, "Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls".

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

import getAuth from '../'; // eslint-disable-line

jest.mock('react-native-firebase', () => {
  return {
    auth: () => {
      return {
        onAuthStateChanged: () => {
          return Promise.resolve({
            name: 'Shaun',
          });
        },
      };
    },
  };
});

it('resolves a promise containing the user', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const response = await getAuth();
  expect(response).toEqual({ name: 'Shaun' });
});
```

Comment: I have 1 feedback that your question title is miss-leading. People don't `unit test` code of 3rd party lib/tools. => it should be "How to `mock/stub/fake` react-native-firebase?" Using right word will help others have a better view to help you :)

Comment: Thanks @Khoa! You make a good point, I've edited the title to reflect your change.

Answer (score 3):

- You returned a resolved promise => nothing would be called after that.
- Your `onAuthStateChanged` is a function with callback

Instead, replace the implement of `onAuthStateChanged` by this:

```
onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn(cb => cb({ name: 'Shaun' }));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I replaced my onAuthStateChanged implementation with yours but I still receive the same error: "Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout." "Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls."

Comment: wow weird :). could you please clarify this: did you use `setTimeout` or `jest.setTimeout`?

Comment: @ShaunSaker : my old answer is not right because I read your code not carefully. I update the answer :) Hope it helps.

Comment: THANK YOU! I have spent hours trying to solve this. Your answer makes sense and works! I really appreciate your help, have a great weekend!

Comment: alternatively I wrote in this answer how I test with react-native-firebase https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815957/how-to-correctly-mock-a-react-native-module-that-utilizes-native-code/55678802#55678802
it might be interesting for you.