# How to correctly mock a React Native module that utilizes native code?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, react-native-firebase

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript. I'm using react-native-firebase for my notifications. I'm furthermore using Jest and Enzyme for my unit tests.

I have the following wrapper function to check the users permissions:

```
export const checkPermissions = (): Promise<boolean> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase
      .messaging()
      .hasPermission()
      .then(enabled => {
        if (enabled) {
          resolve(enabled);
        } else {
          firebase
            .messaging()
            .requestPermission()
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
        }
      });
  });
```

Now I want to test if the function gets called.

Here is the test I wrote:

```
import * as firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import { checkPermissions } from "./notificationHelpers";

jest.mock("react-native-firebase");

describe("checkPermissions", () => {
  beforeEach(async done => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    await checkPermissions();
    done();
  });

  it("should call firebase.messaging().hasPermission()", () => {
    expect(firebase.messaging().hasPermission).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

This throws the error:

```
 FAIL  app/services/utils/core/notificationHelpers/notificationHelpers.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and have run `podinstall`.

     See http://invertase.link/ios for the ios setup guide.

      Error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and haverun `pod install`.
```

So it seems to me that modules that use native code can't simply by auto-mocked.

So I tried to manually mock it. Inside a folder `__mocks__` that's within my root project adjacent to `node_modules` I created a file called `react-native-firebase.ts`, which looks like this:

```
const firebase = {
  messaging: jest.fn(() => ({
    hasPermission: jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true)))
  }))
};

export default firebase;
```

But this code also fails, because `firebase.messaging` is allegedly undefined.

How would one test this stuff?

**EDIT:** Wow, [mocking seems to be completely broken in RN 0.57.x](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20876) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can test code that depends on `react-native-firebase`

Create a manual mock just by adding an empty file in `__mocks__/react-native-firebase.js`, **mocks** folder should be at the same level as `node_modules` as explained [in jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) specifically **Mocking Node modules** section.

With this manual mock you avoid the error

```
    RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and have run `pod install`.
```

Then you don't need `jest.mock("react-native-firebase");` also you don't need to 
test `expect(firebase.messaging().hasPermission).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

What you can do instead is isolate the code that depends on `react-native-firebase` on small functions and then spy on those adding known results.

For example, this verifyPhone function that depends on react-native-firebase.

```
// ./lib/verifyPhoneNumber.ts
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";

const verifyPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
      .on("state_changed", phoneAuthSnapshot => {
        resolve(phoneAuthSnapshot.state);
      });
  });
};

export default verifyPhoneNumber;
```

To test code that depends on `verifyPhoneNumber` function you spy it and replace its implementation like this.

```js
jest.mock("react-native-firebase");

import { signInWithPhone } from "../actions";
import verifyPhoneNumberEpic from "./verifyPhoneNumberEpic";
import { ActionsObservable } from "redux-observable";
// Note "import * as" is needed to use jest.spyOn(verifyPhoneNumber, "default");
import * as verifyPhoneNumber from "./lib/verifyPhoneNumber";

describe("Epic: verifyPhoneNumberEpic", () => {
  test('On Request "[Auth] Verify Phone Number Request" executes the promise', done => {
    // Create the spy
    const verifyPhoneNumberMock = jest.spyOn(verifyPhoneNumber, "default");
    // For this test I simulate the promise resolves with CODE_SENT
    verifyPhoneNumberMock.mockImplementation(async () => "CODE_SENT");
    // the rest of the code is very specific for testing Epics (redux-observable)
    // But all you need to know is that internally my epic verifyPhoneNumberEpic
    // calls verifyPhoneNumber but the implication will be replaced with the spy

    const requestAction = signInWithPhone.request({
      phoneNumber: "+40111222333"
    });
    const action$ = ActionsObservable.of(requestAction);

    verifyPhoneNumberEpic(action$, null, null).subscribe((action: any) => {
      expect(action.payload.code).toBe("CODE_SENT");
      expect(action.type).toBe(signInWithPhone.success.toString());
      done();
    });
  });
```

I hope it helps!